# Как правильно изменить файл .htaccess, чтобы сайт работал на поддомене?

Tags: .htaccess, php

Сайт нормально работает, если размещен по адресу http://domain.com  Нужно его перенести по адресу http:domain.com/music/auto_music/

Файл .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]

RewriteRule ^1aWtPdaeKwG(.*)-(.*) /themes/$1/files.php?type=css&files=$2
RewriteRule ^00cv6P016Bz(.*)-(.*) /themes/$1/files.php?type=javascript&files=$2
RewriteRule ^images_(.*)/(.*)(.*)  /themes/$1/images/$2    [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^play index.php
RewriteRule    ^play?(.*)(/?)+$    index.php?view=play&cal=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^home!logout(/?)+$    index.php?view=home&act=logout    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^activation/(.*)(/?)+$    index.php?stype=$1    [NC,L]

файл config.php
define('WEBSITE_URL', 'http://domain.com'); // YOUR WEBSITE URL
```

Как правильно изменить  файл .htaccess, чтобы сайт работал нормально на поддомене по адресу http:domain.com/music/auto_music/ ?

Простое изменение в config.php   http://domain.com на http:domain.com/music/auto_music/ не дало результатов.

Comment: @Serg1234, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Очевидно используется какой-то движок. Часто перенос сайта в другую директорию не ограничивается только изменениями в htaccess, а требует внесения изменения в конфигурационные файлы или иные настройки движка. Иногда движок принципиально не поддерживает размещение в каком-то каталоге. Вопрос номер один - какой движок вы используете? Вопрос номер два - что за адрес "тут"?

Comment: Подскажите для начала, как править  .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=permanent]
```